# How do I search the most efficient way for a value in several db tables?

Tags: java, sql, backend

Im adding a validation ta a deleteUserMethod in Java. To make sure the User do not have any connections in the db I want to check for that user in several tables in our db.
I thinking something like this:

```
SELECT RoleId FROM Role WHERE Name = 'JH';
SELECT Salary FROM Office WHERE Name = 'JH';
SELECT Position FROM Employees WHERE JH = 'JH';
```

Would you do a simple join?

It would also be good to retrieve some data from that table so that data can be deleted before the user is removed.

Comment: If your database engine supports foreign keys, you should define those and leave the consistency to the database itself.

Comment: It appears that you have some business logic involved whose details you have omitted from your question. Forgive me but my crystal ball is currently being fixed, so unless you are willing to provide details of your business logic, I can only give a guess in response to the last sentence in your question, namely: _It would also be good to retrieve some data from that table so that data can be deleted before the user is removed._ Are you asking how to retrieve and delete data from your database table before deleting the user?

Comment: No foreign keys unfortunately :/ 
Haha sorry, my question was not super clear. I think its only gonna get messy to retrieve data from several tables, so im leaning towards just checking it there is any data connected to that user and than search in the UI to remove that before deleting the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a yes/no answer as to whether the name `JH` exists in any of the three tables, you could just use a single exists query with a union:

```
SELECT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Role WHERE Name = 'JH'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 FROM Office WHERE Name = 'JH'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 FROM Employees WHERE Name = 'JH'
) t;
```

But having to do a query like this might imply poor table design, possibly not normalized properly.  Typically, a query should involve *joins* between one or more tables, rather than a union.

Comment: Thanks! Its probably gonna be something like that, just checking if it exists and block the deletion.